# With crafttweaker, how do you use recipies with items with NBT data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

With CraftTweaker, how do you use recipes with items with NBT data? I am trying to use a singularity with NBT id of `extendedcrafting:netherite_ingot`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can do `/ct hand` with a singularity in you hand.

`<item:extendedcrafting:singularity>.withTag({Id: "thing" as string})`